# Unwanted preservation of variable in cython

Tags: python, cython

I'm running some recursive cython code alongside my main python script; where basically I want to run the cython code while it's within a time limit of 5 seconds. If it's above the time limit, an alternative function will run from my main python code.
Now the issue is not the cython algorithm itself, but the unwanted preservation of the variable that serves as the time threshold *start_time*.

Python code:

```
def python_func(self, cython_hits):
    start_time=time.time()
    print('resetting time',start_time)
    cython_res=root_func_cython(cython_hits,start_time)
```

Cython code:

```
def func1(set var1, float start_time):
    if time()-start_time>5:   
        print('current time',time(),'start time',start_time)
        return None
    res = func1(var1,start_time)
    return res

def root_func_cython(set var1 float start_time):
    print('start time',start_time)
    res = func1(var1, start_time)
    return res
```

So when I compile the code from scratch (**case 1**):

```
$python test_with_cython.py 
(1578175109.4752562, 1578175104.0)
('current time',1578175109.4776363, 'start time',1578175104.0)
('current time',1578175109.479479, 'start time',1578175104.0)
('current time',1578175109.481198, 'start time',1578175104.0)
('current time',1578175109.4832838, 'start time',1578175104.0)
resetting time 1578175109.5146258
('start time', 1578175104.0)
('current time',1578175109.5146704, 'start time',1578175104.0)
FAIL!
```

The start_time is still not being updated but it doesn't immediately crash, only after it passes through the 5 secs threshold. After failing once, all posterior function calls with fail  since the start_time is being preserved.

Now,even weirder, if I **immediately** call the function again (**case 2**)

```
python test_with_cython.py 
resetting time 1578175158.4517117
('start time', 1578175104.0)
('current time',1578175158.4517412, 'start time',1578175104.0)
resetting time 1578175158.4518697
('start time', 1578175104.0)
('current time',1578175158.4518843, 'start time',1578175104.0)
```

It will immediately fail instead since the start_time was preserved!
If I restart the console or wait for a while, the function will go back to case 1.

So my guess is that the variable start_time is being kept in memory somehow? Is it possible to remove it from memory so that the new start_time variable can be sent cython?
I only start working with cython today so I might be missing something very obvious....

Comment: The duplicate says you should use double and not foat.

Comment: Why does this work though? I mean, I get that we need to properly define the type, but why is the value being saved if I wrongly set it as a float instead of double?

Comment: It isn't that the float was being saved wrongly, it's just that a float has half the precision of a double. As the answer in the linked question says, a float is only accurate to the nearest 128 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after fiddling with the code a bit more I just tried to remove the static typing of start_time. I figured, maybe if I don't define it won't do this anymore?

```
def func1(set var1, start_time):
    if time()-start_time>5:   
        print('current time',time(),'start time',start_time)
        return None
    res = func1(var1,start_time)
    return res

def root_func_cython(set var1, start_time):
    print('start time',start_time)
    res = func1(var1, start_time)
    return res
```

So I just removed the float static type (`float static_time`) and it works now....
I don't know why this works but I hope it helps someone in the future.
If anyone has an explanation for this , please feel free to share.